# Insert data into oracle in NVARCHAR2 field with jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Oracle server encoding is AMERICAN.WE8MSWIN1252, and java app encoding is GBK.

I want to insert Chinese characters into an NVARCHAR2 field. I can insert Chinese characters correctly with PLSQL, and PLSQL encoding is also AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252.

**SQL**

```
update TEST_TEST t set t.val = N'测试' where t.id = '1';
```

I also tried `preparedStatement` in `java` app, it works with `setNString`.

When I use sql string joining, I think I need to convert the string encoding:

```
    String value = "测试";
    byte[] destinationBytes = value.getBytes("GBK");
    String value_c = new String(destinationBytes, "Windows-1252");
    String sql = "update TEST_TEST t set t.val22 = N'" + value_c + ".pdf' where t.id = '1'";
```

But, these characters do not display properly.

How can I insert correctly with SQL string joining?

Thanks!

Comment: Do **NOT** concatenate Strings like that. Use a `PreparedStatement`. Not only will that solve your encoding issue it is also more secure and will scale better. Why do you insist on doing it the wrong way if you already know that the correct way (= PreparedStatement) solves your problem?

Comment: Why you don't use UTF-8 in database setting as default charset? (then nothing needed to do and then use varchar2 instead of nvarchar2)

Comment: You can't insert Chinese characters in something with encoding `Windows-1252`, as that encoding **does not support** Chinese characters.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I forgot to say, it's a legacy system. I'm considering the smallest changes, and I can't change the database server side encoding. 
Additionally, if the field is VARCHAR2 type, I can insert those characters by transforming the encoding using sql string joining.